# Smoothness of Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, smooth-functions

I am trying to understand, because the Fourier transform of the function $f(x) = e^{ -\sqrt{ \lvert x \rvert } }$ is smooth.

**My question:** Under which conditions is the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ or $L^2$ function smooth?

---

I think $f$ might be in $L^1$ or $L^2$, but I wasn't able to find a good way to determine that yet. I know that the Fourier transform of a function with compact support is smooth and that if a function is $k$-times differentiable, then the follwing holds for the functions fourrier transform:
$$
\hat{f}(x) \leq \frac{C}{(1+\lvert x \rvert )^{k}}
$$
From the comments and discussion with friends using it appears you have to used the Dominated convergence theorem to exchange derivative and integral, but I struggle to find the dominating function.

Comment: Why doesn’t the integral converge? By the way, $f$ is not smooth at 0, so it’s not Schwartz. But it still decays fast enough to differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: Compact support is not sufficient for a function to have a Fourier Transform.  Unbounded measurable functions might not be integrable and therefore have no FT.

Comment: If $f\in L_1$, $\mathcal{F}f$ is smooth (that is infinitely differentiable) iff $\int|x|^k|f(x)|\,dx<\infty$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$